# css :before and :after are not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

Building a div container with a triangle in lower right hand corner using :before and :after to create orange triangle with white border.  Working well in FF and Chrome.  Not working in IE8.  Tried adjusting z-index and other attributes but not able to figure out what is wrong here.  Any help is appreciated.

```
 .homepage-banner-main:after { 
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 100;
     bottom: 0px;
     right:5px;
     border-top: 100px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; 
     border-right:100px solid #e66c23; 
     zoom:1;
 }

 .homepage-banner-main:before { 
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 100;
     bottom: 0px;
     right:5px;
     border-top: 110px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; 
     border-right:110px solid white; 
     zoom:1; 
 }

      <div class="homepage-banner-main" id="banner-1" >
          <img src="http://fillmurray.com/g/710/400" >
      </div>
```

Comment: can you please your entire DOCTYPE?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a number of reasons. Out of the top of my head, can you check that:

1. Your page is NOT running in Quirks Mode.
2. Your page is passing HTML validation (go to [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) to do a quick check.)

Comment: Here is head section.  Not in quirks mode.  Will check validator.   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Comment: Checked out validator and fixed all issues.  Still not showing triangle on top of image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure following in your header

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Make sure you are closing meta as well.  `<meta -------  />`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

similarly

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
```